# The CSS selector "hover" is not working on my HTML code

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my `:hover` isn't working. Here's my CSS code:

```
.image:hover
{
    border:#000000;
    background-color:#FF66FF;
    box-shadow:rgb(0,255,153);
}
```

And my HTML

```
 <div id="header">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="header.png" class="image" onload="ChangeColors(this)" /></a>
 </div>
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: which browser is it not working in?

Comment: What's `onload="ChangeColors(this)"`?

Comment: Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please?

Comment: @AntonyScott Firefox.  elclanrs: It's a function that changes the color of my logo to a random color (not related).

Comment: A note: you can omit the `<a>...</a>` and merge `href` into the `img` tag, and it has the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working - you just have to correct your CSS rules.

For `border` you have to specify its width and style, not just color. Same for the `box-shadow` - the color itself isn't enough.

```css
.image:hover {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color:#FF66FF;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgb(0,255,153);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" class="image" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks...  I felt kinda dumb not being able to work out a problem as simple as that lol.

Answer (score 0):

The class="image" needs moving to your A tag

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working just fine:

- http://jsfiddle.net/DpBRY/

You have some pink background on hover... Firefox 11.0 on Ubuntu 11.10 here.

Here's an update for `border` and `box-shadow`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/DpBRY/2/

but you can of course tune to your taste. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `header.png` is not transparent?

Comment: I notice you are trying to change its background color.